# how to convert WAV format to FLAC using libFLAC++

Tags: c++, c++builder, flac

how to convert WAV format to FLAC using libFLAC++
(encode.h and decode.h)

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 3):

There's a nice C++ example in the *libflac* source tarball.

It's also possible to [browse it online](http://flac.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/flac/flac/examples/cpp/encode/file/main.cpp?view=markup) (single cpp file).

- [Decode](http://flac.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/flac/flac/examples/cpp/decode/)
- [Encode](http://flac.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/flac/flac/examples/cpp/encode/)

Comment: Seriously, do you expect to find an example ready to double click n' compile with C++ Builder? There's nothing specific to VC++ in the `main.cpp`. Just remove everything but the `main.cpp` and create a new C++ Builder project with it. C++ is a standard language, VC++ is not a language but an IDE. `libflac` is standard C++.

Comment: On the FLAC website there's even a link to a set of precompiled tools, which let you do that directly: https://xiph.org/flac/download.html The source code of these tools can also be found on said website.